# Sprite Kit Scene Size Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my Sprite Kit project, I had a scene that was configured very well and all of the user interface elements were laid out nicely. I decided to put a menu scene before this one, and I have this menu scene display the original scene.

Everything is now thrown off. The entire scene seems to be zoomed out, and everything is smaller. Any clues as to why this may have happened? I'm not certain as to what the relevant code may be, so I just included the presentation of my original Scene.

```
SKScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;

SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1];

//present game view scene
[self.view presentScene:scene transition:transition];
```

Comment: check the size with which the scene is initialized, perhaps x/y are swapped

Comment: Width is found to be 568

Comment: Height is found to be 320